# HTTP Error 503.2 - Service Unavailable. The serverRuntime@appConcurrentRequestLimit setting is being exceeded

Tags: iis, iis-7, sitecore

I have a intranet SiteCore website set up on IIS 7 which randomly throws the following error message

```
    HTTP Error 503.2 - Service Unavailable
    The serverRuntime@appConcurrentRequestLimit setting is being exceeded.
```

To fix this issue, I have made following changes

- Increased the Queue Length of application pool myrjetAppPool from 1000 to 65535.
- Modified Machine.Config to increase requestQueueLimit property of ProcessModel element to 100000
- Increased appConcurrentRequestLimit to 10000 by running

  ```
  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:serverRuntime /appConcurrentRequestLimit:100000
  ```

But I'm still getting the same error. ANy help is greatly appreaciated.

Comment: How much traffic is that server getting? Have a look at performance counters for that application pool and let us know what you find out.

Comment: @PaulGeorge Sorry for the delay, actually developers found out that there was problem with the package because of which certain page was getting 2millions requests per day and this caused the issue. Once developers fixed the issue, things fell in place.

Comment: Another option is to add the appConcurrentRequestLimit directly to a single web.config instead of the entire IIS config, that way you can control each application/website individually.  Just make sure this path is in the web.config: <configuration><system.webServer> <serverRuntime appConcurrentRequestLimit="10000" />... if it throws an error you might have to unlock that section using "appcmd.exe unlock config /section:serverRuntime"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Investigate references in the linked url to 'MaxConcurrentReqeustsPerCPU' which you may need to set by creating a new registry key, depending on your OS and framework.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tmarq/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-5-iis-7-0-and-iis-6-0

As already commented - check the actual concurrent request count using performance counters to determine which limit you're hitting i.e. it could be a limit of 5000 or maybe 12 (per cpu).

**Edit:** I realise this may look like I'm talking about a different setting entirely, but I believe there is overlap here.

Answer (score 7):

You might check to see where all your threads are going.  We had occurrences where threads for Media Library assets were hanging and blocking up the queue.

In IIS Manager, select the server node from the tree, then the "Worker Processes" feature icon, then right-click the application pool of interest and select "View current requests".  You might find something is getting stuck.  I sometimes hit F5 on this screen a few dozen times in very quick succession to see the rate the requests are going through (of course Performance Monitor is better for viewing metrics but it won't tell you what URLs are being processed).

Answer (score 0):

We got this problem after an installation of an IIS plugin. After long investigating we saw that the config-file C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config  had an extra location tag for the site with the problem. After removing the extra entry and an iisreset, the site/server worked normally againg. So something must went wrong during the installation....