# Setting appConcurrentRequestLimit in Windows 2008

Tags: windows, iis

I read from SO ([HTTP Error 503.2 - Service Unavailable. The serverRuntime@appConcurrentRequestLimit setting is being exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774826/http-error-503-2-service-unavailable-the-serverruntimeappconcurrentrequestli)) and MSDN (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425294(v=office.13).aspx) that I need to set AppConCurrentRequestLimit to a bigger number if the site is showing appconcurrentlimit exceeded error (which mine is like that).

However upon executing the command provided by MSDN, I got error

```
c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe set config /section:serverRuntime /appCon
currentRequestLimit:100000
ERROR ( message:Unknown attribute "appConcurrentRequestLimit".  Replace with -?
for help. )
```

1. I try to search in google but seems no one having the same issue as mine.
2. I try to manually input in ASPNET.Config in XML but whatever I change the site does not seem to restart, even I put random error text in the config, my site still does not show error, is ASPNET.Config configuration being used, why there is no error even the configuration is intentionally made error?

Answer (score 4):

It fails if you have additional sections such as ftpsection. 
In order to edit the serverRuntime of the system.webserver section you should run:

```
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv
appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webserver/serverRuntime /appConcurrentRequestLimit:100000
```