# SignalR Core connections not being closed and bringing down IIS

Tags: cloudflare, signalrcore

We have SignalR Core running in IIS and the connections are not being closed over time.

This results in a [503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774826/http-error-503-2-service-unavailable-the-serverruntimeappconcurrentrequestli/9802715#9802715) error:

```
HTTP Error 503.2 - Service Unavailable
The serverRuntime@appConcurrentRequestLimit setting is being exceeded.
```

[image]

When recycling the apppool the **Current Connections** will drop to 0 and then back up to around 50 (as actual clients reconnect). Over the course of a day it can easily reach 2000. Not every connection is leaking - the number does decrease but trends upwards over time.

Latest .NET Core 3.1 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

We are using [Argo Tunnel](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/argo-tunnel/) which creates a tunnel from our webserver to the Cloudflare network.

Turns out it was an out of date `cloudflared` executable.

The version we were running was from 5/2019 and updating to the new version from 12/2019 has fixed the problem. In fact when stopping the cloudflare service all the connections instantly dropped away.